# Any way to extract music from Nintendo Wii Games?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I love the music from some of the Nintendo Wii games, like *A Boy and His Blob* or *Super Mario Galaxy*. Is there any way to extract the music from these games digitally so I can listen to it on my computer? I know I could just hook my Wii up to my computer and record the music, but I'm looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try first looking to see if there are composed albums of the sound track. You'll be endorsing the availability of the music separate from the game (many already are sold as MP3s, but a CD is still easier to rip than extracting from a game) which hopefully will entice publishers to make the sound tracks for other games available for sale as well.

examples:
[Super Mario Galaxy 1 & 2](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A5174%2Ck%3Asuper+mario+galaxy%2Cn%3A%21301668%2Cn%3A42&bbn=301668&keywords=super+mario+galaxy&ie=UTF8&qid=1291935929&rnid=301668)
[A Boy and His Blob](http://www.originalsoundversion.com/a-boy-and-his-blob-original-soundtrack-blobs-on-the-wii-make-great-music-review/) (to be released "soon")

Comment: WOAH I CAN BUY THE BLOB SOUNDTRACK!?!?! *SWEEEETTT!!!!*

Comment: Awesome, [it is on iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/a-boy-and-his-blob/id396784290)!

Comment: This is not an answer. This answer also does not apply to the 99.9% of Wii games that do not have soundtracks for sale. This is just a "go buy this instead answer."

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible? For some games it is, but it can't be a general "yes". Not all games use the same music format, so it depends whether someone has already programmed a decoder/player for the specific game's format.

[vgmstream](http://hcs64.com/vgmstream.html) can play many formats, so you can probably give that a shot. You'll have to locate the music files on the game disc though, which may itself be a difficult task.

Comment: "Not all games use the same music format" -- ah, I guess that was kind of my question. I wasn't sure if the Wii had a standard music format.

Comment: @Josh: There probably *is* a standard format, but not every game will use it for everything. At least, that's how it is on the DS: most (if not all) games use the .SDAT file format for sound effects and usually some amount of MIDI/MOD-like music, but some games go beyond that as well - for example, [The World Ends With You](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Ends_with_You) uses .ADX files for the music. And of course, that's completely ignoring videos, which also contain audio.

Answer (score 1):

## Extract Audio With Trucha

1. Open Wii ISO in [Trucha](https://filetrip.net/wiiu-downloads/other-files/download-trucha-signer-0-22-f26019.html)
2. Extract Audio files. Good luck finding them. They could be in .brstm format or something else. One method is to just start dropping everything into VLC until it starts playing music and convert them to a desired format with VLC.

Here's an alternative audio player.

1. Start Winamp
2. <s>Install plugin if not already done so</s> 
   [vgmstream now comes with Winamp so it should just play right away.](http://www.hcs64.com/vgmstream.html)
3. Export audio to desired format.

https://gbatemp.net/threads/tutorial-trucha-signer-tutorial.76657/